# Is it possible to create an EF Core many-to-one with a filter and no foreign key? How?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a navigation one-to-many that will not require a foreign key. Also, I want to filter this navigation. It is better to show than to write:

```cs
class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public virtual ICollection<TagEntity> Tags { get; set; }
}

class Truck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public virtual ICollection<TagEntity> Tags { get; set; }
}

class TagEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityTypeId { get; set; }
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Truck> Trucks { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<TagEntity> TagEntities { get; set; } = null!;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(c => {
            c.HasMany(e => e.Tags); //TODO HERE: only tags where EntityTypeId = 1
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Truck>(t => {
            t.HasMany(e => e.Tags); //TODO HERE: only tags where EntityTypeId = 2
        });
    }
}
```

The above code can be run in this site: https://efplayground.io/migrations

It will generate this migration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Cars] 
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] nvarchar(32) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cars] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Trucks]  
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] nvarchar(32) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Trucks] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [TagEntities]  
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [EntityId] int NOT NULL,
    [EntityTypeId] int NOT NULL,
    [CarId] int NULL,
    [TruckId] int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TagEntities] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TagEntities_Cars_CarId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CarId]) REFERENCES [Cars] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TagEntities_Trucks_TruckId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([TruckId]) REFERENCES [Trucks] ([Id])
);

CREATE INDEX [IX_TagEntities_CarId] ON [TagEntities] ([CarId]);
CREATE INDEX [IX_TagEntities_TruckId] ON [TagEntities] ([TruckId]);
```

Where I don't want these foreign key to be generated (and I don't want to manually edit the generated migration):

```sql
CONSTRAINT [FK_TagEntities_Cars_CarId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CarId]) REFERENCES [Cars] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_TagEntities_Trucks_TruckId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([TruckId]) REFERENCES [Trucks] ([Id])
```

Is it possible to add filters to the model builder (please, see TODO in the code above)?

Is it possible to prevent the creation of the mentioned foreign keys?
How?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should ask first "is it possible to create a relation in relational database without foreign key" or "is it possible to reference multiple tables in a single foreign key column".

Comment: If you drop all the foreign key constraints from the database just for fun, the EF mapping would stop working?

Comment: These *polymorphic associations* should be avoided. Just create two Tag tables. I can't tell you how much trouble it would have saved me if I had known that earlier.

Comment: I totally agree (almost in tears). But it is a legacy table :(

Comment: If you can't change the scheme than don't expose the relationship in EF Core because there is no one (in SQL terms).

Comment: I want to expose it. I appreciate your time, but I would be glad if anyone could suggest how to do that or if someone is sure is not possible, please advise me. I'm not looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have an existing database model containing a `TagEntities` table that doesn't have the "hard" foreign key fields `CarId` and `TruckId`, only `EntityId` and `EntityTypeId`.

In EF core, such a model can be mapped by subclassing `TagEntity`:

```cs
class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarTag> Tags { get; set; } // Collection of subclass!
}

class Truck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TruckTag> Tags { get; set; } // Collection of subclass!
}

abstract class TagEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityTypeId { get; set; }
}

class CarTag : TagEntity { }
class TruckTag : TagEntity { }
```

This is the configuration in `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TagEntity>().ToTable("TagEntities");
modelBuilder.Entity<CarTag>().HasDiscriminator(t => t.EntityTypeId).HasValue(1);
modelBuilder.Entity<TruckTag>().HasDiscriminator(t => t.EntityTypeId).HasValue(2);
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasMany(e => e.Tags).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.EntityId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Truck>().HasMany(e => e.Tags).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.EntityId);
```

Now when querying `context.Cars.Include(c => c.Tags)`, you get this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [t0].[Id], [t0].[EntityId], [t0].[EntityTypeId], [t0].[Name]
FROM [Cars] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[EntityId], [t].[EntityTypeId], [t].[Name]
    FROM [TagEntities] AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[EntityTypeId] = 1
) AS [t0] ON [c].[Id] = [t0].[EntityId]
ORDER BY [c].[Id]
```

So the `JOIN` is on `EntityId` but the results are confined to `[EntityTypeId] = 1`.

Note that this will fail miserably when migrations will generate a database model, because `EntityId` will be a foreign key to both `Car` and `Truck`.

When creating a new model for such a setup with *polymorphic associations*, I've experienced that in the end it's always better to just duplicate the tables: `CarTags` and `TruckTags`.